# ReferenceError: $ is not defined at null.js:4:1

Tags: javascript, jquery

My homework is to create a calculator code. I am getting this error when trying to create a JavaScript and jQuery calculator.

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined
> at null.js:4:1

This is my code:

```
 * Implement all your JavaScript in this file!
 */
$(function () {
    console.log("ready!");
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    var result = 0;
    var prevEntry = 0;
    var operation = null;
    var currentEntry = '0';
    var operators = ['+', '-', '*', '/', '=', 'C'];
    var buffer = '';
    var currentResult = 0;
    var currentOperation = '';
    updateScreen(result);
});

$(function createKeys()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var key = document.createElement('div');
        key.innerHTML = i;
        key.dataset.value = i;
        key.className = 'key';

        document.getElementById('numpad').appendChild(key);
    }

    operators.forEach(function (item) {
        var key = document.createElement('div');
        key.innerHTML = item;
        key.dataset.operation = item;
        key.className = 'key';

        document.getElementById('operators').appendChild(key);
    });
});

operate = function (a, b, operation) {
    a = parseFloat(a);
    b = parseFloat(b);
    console.log(a, b, operation);
    if (operation === '+') return a + b;
    if (operation === '-') return a - b;
    if (operation === '*') return a * b;
    if (operation === '/') return a / b;
}
```

My folder path to the JS folder looks like this: C:\Users\Extreme PC\Pictures\edX\Programming for the Web with JavaScript/Week two/Homework Three

I'm new to coding, so this should be a simple task. As far as I know, I needed a for loop to make the calculator function. I don't know how or what else to continue with the code.

Comment: Have you imported jquery? It would also be useful to see your html. Preferably as a snippet here. Also, your path to js files should be relative to your index file, not based on where on your computer it is.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/A3uBPF7U Here's my html. I'll try changing the file location.

Comment: I see a script tag looking for jQuery at the bottom of your HTML but the error certainly makes it seem like jQuery is missing here.  If you open your browser developer tools and look at the network pane while doing a fresh load of the page, you can see if the request to jQuery is actually succeeding or if it is failing for some reason.

Comment: `<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="calc.js"></script>`

I took out the script at the bottom of my HTML and replaced it at the top.